# Sorting in sub aggregated result of a sub sub aggregated in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to rewrite the SQL Query to NOSQL Query.

```
 SELECT     count(1) as total,
    count(CASE WHEN updated >= now() - '1 day'::interval THEN 1 END) as daily,
    count(CASE WHEN updated >= now() - '7 day'::interval THEN 1 END) as weekly,
    count(CASE WHEN updated >= now() - '30 day'::interval THEN 1 END) as monthly,
    status_code, state

    FROM alerts
    GROUP BY status_code, state
    ORDER BY total DESC, status_code, state
```

Following is output for SQL Query

```
   total    |    daily   |   weekly    |     monthly   |   status_code   |    state
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2           0               0               1           test1           ACTIVE          
    2           0               1               2           test1           INACTIVE            
    2           1               1               1           test2           INACTIVE            
    1           0               0               1           test3           ACTIVE
```

I got struck while ordering the 'total' column while writing NOSQL Query

Below is the NOSQL Query i used

```
{
            "stateAggregation": {
             "terms": {
                "field": "state"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "statusCodeAggregation": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "status_code"
                  } ,
                  "aggs": {
                       "total" : {
                            "date_range": {
                                "field": "updated",
                                "ranges": [{ "to": "now" }]
                             }
                         },
                         "daily" : {
                           "date_range": {
                                "field": "updated",
                                "ranges": [{ "from": "now-1d/d" }]
                            }
                         },
                         "weekly" : {
                            "date_range": {
                                "field": "updated",
                                "ranges": [{ "from": "now-7d/d" }]
                            }
                         },
                         "monthly" : {
                            "date_range": {
                                "field": "updated",
                                "ranges": [{ "from": "now-30d/d" }]
                            }
                         }
                      }          
                }
              }
            }
        }
```

Following is output for NOSQL Query

```
{
  "took" : 8,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "stateAggregation" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "active",
        "doc_count" : 3,
        "statusCodeAggregation" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [ {
            "key" : "test 1",
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "weekly" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "2015-09-04T00:00:00.000Z-*",
                "from" : 1.4413248E12,
                "from_as_string" : "2015-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                "doc_count" : 0
              } ]
            },
            "total" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "*-2015-09-11T12:42:58.463Z",
                "to" : 1.441975378463E12,
                "to_as_string" : "2015-09-11T12:42:58.463Z",
                "doc_count" : 2
              } ]
            },
            "monthly" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "2015-08-12T00:00:00.000Z-*",
                "from" : 1.4393376E12,
                "from_as_string" : "2015-08-12T00:00:00.000Z",
                "doc_count" : 1
              } ]
            },
            "daily" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "2015-09-10T00:00:00.000Z-*",
                "from" : 1.4418432E12,
                "from_as_string" : "2015-09-10T00:00:00.000Z",
                "doc_count" : 0
              } ]
            }
          }, {
            "key" : "test",
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "weekly" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "2015-09-04T00:00:00.000Z-*",
                "from" : 1.4413248E12,
                "from_as_string" : "2015-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                "doc_count" : 1
              } ]
            },
            "total" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "*-2015-09-11T12:42:58.463Z",
                "to" : 1.441975378463E12,
                "to_as_string" : "2015-09-11T12:42:58.463Z",
                "doc_count" : 1
              } ]
            },
            "monthly" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "2015-08-12T00:00:00.000Z-*",
                "from" : 1.4393376E12,
                "from_as_string" : "2015-08-12T00:00:00.000Z",
                "doc_count" : 1
              } ]
            },
            "daily" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "2015-09-10T00:00:00.000Z-*",
                "from" : 1.4418432E12,
                "from_as_string" : "2015-09-10T00:00:00.000Z",
                "doc_count" : 1
              } ]
            }
          } ]
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "mute",
        "doc_count" : 2,
        "statusCodeAggregation" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [ {
            "key" : "test",
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "weekly" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "2015-09-04T00:00:00.000Z-*",
                "from" : 1.4413248E12,
                "from_as_string" : "2015-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                "doc_count" : 1
              } ]
            },
            "total" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "*-2015-09-11T12:42:58.463Z",
                "to" : 1.441975378463E12,
                "to_as_string" : "2015-09-11T12:42:58.463Z",
                "doc_count" : 2
              } ]
            },
            "monthly" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "2015-08-12T00:00:00.000Z-*",
                "from" : 1.4393376E12,
                "from_as_string" : "2015-08-12T00:00:00.000Z",
                "doc_count" : 2
              } ]
            },
            "daily" : {
              "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "2015-09-10T00:00:00.000Z-*",
                "from" : 1.4418432E12,
                "from_as_string" : "2015-09-10T00:00:00.000Z",
                "doc_count" : 1
              } ]
            }
          } ]
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me out in modifying the NOSQL query for applying order on 'total' aggregation?

When i try to add order on total in status code aggregation

```
"statusCodeAggregation": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "status_code",
                   "order" :{ "total._count" : "desc" }
                  }
```

Then i got the following error

AggregationExecutionException[Invalid terms aggregation order path [total._count]. Terms buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end.]}